# Spring Injection of Data using Hibernate

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

On initialisation of the web app, I am trying to inject some static data from the DB into the bean.

```
<bean id="CustomDriven" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>#{FormCodeHibernateDAO.findAll()}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I get an error

> 6:48:07,977 INFO  [main] [UpdateTimestampsCache] starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
>   16:48:07,981 INFO  [main] [StandardQueryCache] starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
>   16:48:09,016 DEBUG [main] [GenericDaoJpa] findAll()
>   16:48:09,017 DEBUG [main] [GenericDaoJpa] getting HIBERNATE session...
>   16:48:09,196 ERROR [main] [GenericDaoJpa] Error when finding all
>   org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.setFlushMode(SessionImpl.java:1433)

Any reason why I am getting this?

Comment: Without knowing what `FormCodeHibernateDAO` is, or what it does, or how it does it, then how can we know?

Comment: FormCodeHibernateDAO just extends a generic implementation of a DAO, which has findByName, findByCode, findAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem, my CustomDriven bean was talking to the DAO Impl directly.

I changed it to talk to the DAO using a service and the new configuration looks like

```
<bean id="CustomDriven" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>#{dataDrivenService.getDataList()}</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

And the DataDriverService class is

```
public interface DataDrivenService<T> {

    public List<T> getDataList();
 }
```

And the ServiceImpl is

```
@Service( value = "dataDrivenService" )
public class DataDrivenServiceImpl implements DataDrivenService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( value = "formCodeDAO" )
    private FormCodeDAO dao;

    @Override
    @Transactional( readOnly = true )
    public List<FormCode> getDataList() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Where FormCodeDAO in interface that extends the GenericDAO implementation

Answer (score 0):

maybe the execution of #{FormCodeHibernateDAO.findAll()} is before than the application context start connection to database, i think so.

Comment: Don't think that's the case, I have the persistence to create-drop and in the logs i see the tables created and data populated.